# Are there technical means to enforce aircraft speed limits as well as regulatory means?

Tags: aircraft-design, airspeed

Do any aircraft have a device which can be pre-set or can be controlled from the ground in order to prevent the aircraft from exceeding a speed limit?

These could be similar to what they have for buses in many places so the bus driver can't go beyond a speed limit.

Comment: 1) Air traffic control can request a speed, but they have no way to impose it. 2) Where are these 'many places' that buses have limiters? I could find only the Philippines with plans to install them.

Comment: I have seen them on London buses and some places in India as well.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limiter

Comment: That Wikipedia article is dreadful. The section on UK buses refers only to statutory speed limits, and makes no reference at all to hardware installed in the buses themselves.  There are no sources listed for many of its assertions. India's plans to install limiters cover new vehicles from 1st October 2015 - that's hardly 'many places'.

Comment: I think that such a device would be incredibly dangerous to have on a plane. Airplanes fly by going fast, and some situations might require a higher speed to remain airborne.

Comment: Anything that could control an aircraft from outside would not be accepted (unless we talk about proposals in the event of hijack etc).  The only people who have the full picture and the context required to manipulate the controls are inside the aircraft.

Comment: @airsick The article isn't perfect but I'm not sure why you're insistent on being argumentative. The EU does insist on physical speed limiters being implemented on many vehicles and they're now extremely common on busses, HGVs and vans.

Comment: What problem would such a device would solve? If there's no need for the device, there's no reason it would exist.

Comment: For what it's worth, many trucks, busses, etc. have speed limiters in them even here in the US.  Mostly commercial vehicles that are trying to limit liability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some aircraft have flight envelope protections which, among other things, aim to prevent the aircraft exceeding a predefined maximum airspeed.

> High Speed Protection:
>
> Prevents exceeding VMO or MMO by introducing a pitch up load factor demand.
> The pilot can NOT override the pitch up command.

- [AirbusDriver.net](http://www.airbusdriver.net/airbus_fltlaws.htm)

Note that these are structural safety limits, people on the ground cannot use this feature to impose arbitrary speed limits by geographic area, time of day etc.

Comment: What does it do if pitching up sharply enough to keep the plane from exceeding VMO/MMO would itself cause the aircraft to exceed structural safety limits?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.
Speed control is somewhat more complicated in an aircraft. Surely it would be technically possible to install a device that would limit engine power, but it cannot control speed.
Once airborne, you can always increase speed by pitching the nose down or decrease speed by pitching up. Similar effect can alter speed when flying through strong up- or downdrafts while maintaining level flight.

Comment: Just pointing out that thrust is not the only way to control airspeed.

Comment: I disagree. It is possible to set a target speed or a speed limit, but you cannot prevent the aircraft from exceeding it in some situations.

Comment: You can do the same as in the alleged bus: prevent the pilot to intentionally move faster than a limit. Now neither the aircraft or the bus can be prevented to exceed this speed in some situation where the force is not under control, e.g. sudden change in slope for bus (we see that in our car speed limiter), or sudden change of angle of attack in an aircraft. But overall this works (and I suppose that's the intent of the question to understand this) if we allow a delay between the event and the feedback.

Comment: I agree fully on your last comment. The keyword is "intentionally". However I understood the question more literally, and therefore my answer is no, exceeding a speed limit cannot be prevented by a device.